# R delete rows of list element and keep rownames

Tags: r, list, row, names

I have a dataframe with empty cells that I split into a list:

```
df <- data.frame(c("q","w","","r","t","y"),c("a","b","","d","e","f"),c("x","c","v","b","","m"))
colnames(df) <- c("qwerty","abc","bnm")
rownames(df) <- c("1a","1b","1c","1d","1e","1f")
list <- lapply(df, as.data.frame)
for(i in 1:length(list)){  rownames(list[[i]]) <- rownames(df) }
```

However, when I remove the empty rows from one of the list's elements, rownames are deleted for that element:

```
list[[1]] <- list[[1]][list[[1]] != "",]
rownames(list[[1]])
NULL
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The row names were "deleted" because you converted your data frame to a vector (which don't have row names  by definition).

This is happening when you are trying to subset a `data.frame` which contains only one column. In order to prevent this, use `drop = FALSE` as in:

```
lapply(list, function(x) x[x != "",, drop = FALSE])
# $qwerty
#     X[[1L]]
# 1a       q
# 1b       w
# 1d       r
# 1e       t
# 1f       y
# 
# $abc
#    X[[2L]]
# 1a       a
# 1b       b
# 1d       d
# 1e       e
# 1f       f
# 
# $bnm
#    X[[3L]]
# 1a       x
# 1b       c
# 1c       v
# 1d       b
# 1f       m
```

---

In order to illustrate this, consider the following example

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("a", "", "b"))
(subdf <- df[df$A != "", ])
# [1] a b
# Levels:  a b
class(subdf)
# [1] "factor"
rownames(subdf)
# NULL
```

---

For further information see `?"[.data.frame"`

> **drop**
>
> logical. If TRUE the result is coerced to the lowest possible
>   dimension. **The default is to drop if only one column is left**, but not
>   to drop if only one row is left.

Comment: I didn't know this about data.frames, thanks for your extensive explanation!